# Neural Net adapts to change in output instead of learning features

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I was trying to implement a Neural Net from scratch on the IRIS dataset. However, instead of learning the features in the dataset the network simply kept changing the prediction probabilities to suit the output, i.e., As soon as a new output came the probability of that output increased while others decreased.

Here are my Square-Error,Softmax and Square-Error Derivative functons:-

```
def SE(yHatarr, yarr):
    yHatarr=yHatarr[0];ans=[]
    for i in range(len(yarr)):
        ans.append(0.5*(yHatarr[i]-yarr[i])**2)
    return [ans]
def softmax(arr):
    arr=arr[0]
    ctr=sum([np.exp(i) for i in arr])
    ans=[]
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        ans.append(np.exp(arr[i])/ctr)
    return [ans]
def SEd(yHatarr, yarr):
    yHatarr=yHatarr[0];ans=[]
    for i in range(len(yarr)):
        ans.append(yHatarr[i]-yarr[i])
    return [ans]
```

Keep an eye out for how the Predicted_Probability changes as soon as the correct output changes from [0,0,1] to [1,0,0].

Here is an Example of the output from the neurons:-

```
Format:- [Prob_Class1,Prob_Class2,Prob_Class3] [True Class] Error

[0.08 0.87 0.05 ][0 0 1] 0.8355123456043121
[0.08 0.86 0.06 ][0 0 1] 0.8201579522256677
[0.09 0.85 0.07 ][0 0 1] 0.7995375042585138
[0.10 0.83 0.08 ][0 0 1] 0.7766517570676785
[0.10 0.81 0.09 ][0 0 1] 0.7481394857171886
[0.11 0.78 0.10 ][0 0 1] 0.7147686941406041
[0.12 0.76 0.12 ][0 0 1] 0.6782722653829699
[0.13 0.72 0.15 ][0 0 1] 0.6298704268963138
[0.14 0.68 0.18 ][0 0 1] 0.5776411760112319
[0.15 0.63 0.22 ][0 0 1] 0.5131507663831025
[0.16 0.58 0.26 ][0 0 1] 0.4493113237770373
[0.16 0.52 0.32 ][0 0 1] 0.3831032130730988
[0.16 0.47 0.37 ][0 0 1] 0.31710665107283553
[0.15 0.42 0.43 ][0 0 1] 0.26146891484458623
[0.15 0.37 0.48 ][0 0 1] 0.21150581119605297
[0.14 0.32 0.53 ][0 0 1] 0.1717355634863632
[0.13 0.29 0.58 ][0 0 1] 0.14168474990198907
[0.13 0.26 0.61 ][0 0 1] 0.11669936303086509
[0.12 0.24 0.64 ][0 0 1] 0.09947807429495423
[0.11 0.22 0.67 ][0 0 1] 0.08728858698649153
[0.11 0.20 0.69 ][0 0 1] 0.07416948011896661
[0.10 0.19 0.71 ][0 0 1] 0.06615338011546637
[0.10 0.18 0.73 ][0 0 1] 0.057605179280366875
[0.09 0.17 0.74 ][0 0 1] 0.05265220063231083
[0.09 0.16 0.75 ][0 0 1] 0.046785733140138064
[0.09 0.15 0.76 ][0 0 1] 0.042482200219891866
[0.08 0.14 0.77 ][0 0 1] 0.0396332613686496
[0.08 0.14 0.78 ][0 0 1] 0.03633626094906805
[0.08 0.13 0.79 ][0 0 1] 0.033367106642829145
[0.07 0.13 0.80 ][0 0 1] 0.03084241102227691
[0.07 0.12 0.81 ][0 0 1] 0.028763190819509295
[0.07 0.12 0.81 ][0 0 1] 0.026683698305330142
[0.07 0.11 0.82 ][0 0 1] 0.025496619777046432
[0.07 0.11 0.82 ][0 0 1] 0.02419286952170306
[0.07 0.11 0.83 ][0 0 1] 0.022735851321869192
[0.06 0.10 0.83 ][0 0 1] 0.021315209520257297
[0.06 0.10 0.84 ][0 0 1] 0.02031128142500064
[0.06 0.10 0.84 ][0 0 1] 0.01943104743984881
[0.06 0.10 0.84 ][0 0 1] 0.018748933049037395
[0.06 0.09 0.85 ][0 0 1] 0.017691330851158107
[0.06 0.09 0.85 ][0 0 1] 0.016885822752465505
[0.06 0.09 0.85 ][0 0 1] 0.016275209414762362
[0.06 0.09 0.86 ][0 0 1] 0.015776698478290732
[0.06 0.08 0.86 ][0 0 1] 0.01488144258331394
[0.05 0.08 0.86 ][0 0 1] 0.014335498578266635
[0.05 0.08 0.86 ][0 0 1] 0.013945092246224356
[0.05 0.08 0.87 ][0 0 1] 0.013625021482995811
[0.05 0.08 0.87 ][0 0 1] 0.013014934792770029
[0.05 0.08 0.87 ][0 0 1] 0.012500751350839438
[0.05 0.08 0.87 ][0 0 1] 0.012226730308986347
[0.05 0.08 0.87 ][1 0 0] 0.82624996642836
[0.06 0.08 0.85 ][1 0 0] 0.8072553055841852
[0.07 0.09 0.84 ][1 0 0] 0.7853602251838425
[0.08 0.10 0.82 ][1 0 0] 0.7619773134178103
[0.10 0.10 0.80 ][1 0 0] 0.7324226143564783
[0.11 0.11 0.77 ][1 0 0] 0.7001594230119894
[0.14 0.12 0.74 ][1 0 0] 0.6549562589875634
[0.16 0.13 0.71 ][1 0 0] 0.6087388567926084
[0.20 0.14 0.66 ][1 0 0] 0.5525454038670237
[0.23 0.15 0.62 ][1 0 0] 0.49434468417325117
[0.28 0.15 0.56 ][1 0 0] 0.4279669053631815
[0.33 0.16 0.51 ][1 0 0] 0.3640007597877611
[0.39 0.15 0.46 ][1 0 0] 0.3027515636324625
[0.45 0.15 0.40 ][1 0 0] 0.24527733282462752
[0.50 0.14 0.36 ][1 0 0] 0.1996751453608583
[0.54 0.14 0.32 ][1 0 0] 0.16499312667280702
[0.58 0.13 0.29 ][1 0 0] 0.13579401354879722
[0.62 0.12 0.26 ][1 0 0] 0.1158698305331455
[0.64 0.12 0.24 ][1 0 0] 0.09984949418039146
[0.67 0.11 0.22 ][1 0 0] 0.08490903381373108
[0.69 0.11 0.21 ][1 0 0] 0.0762273750979035
[0.71 0.10 0.19 ][1 0 0] 0.0650603698708109
[0.73 0.09 0.18 ][1 0 0] 0.056831046615074626
[0.74 0.09 0.17 ][1 0 0] 0.05322067257195143
[0.75 0.09 0.16 ][1 0 0] 0.049471523570271556
[0.76 0.09 0.15 ][1 0 0] 0.04501377897284836
[0.77 0.08 0.15 ][1 0 0] 0.039889681824408205
[0.78 0.08 0.14 ][1 0 0] 0.036874399389275316
[0.79 0.08 0.13 ][1 0 0] 0.03406101493411523
[0.79 0.08 0.13 ][1 0 0] 0.03253282476808503
[0.80 0.07 0.13 ][1 0 0] 0.030510155182873304
[0.81 0.07 0.12 ][1 0 0] 0.027467136216565744
[0.82 0.07 0.11 ][1 0 0] 0.02571578615714047
[0.82 0.07 0.11 ][1 0 0] 0.02394192291624685
[0.82 0.07 0.11 ][1 0 0] 0.024099987904135103
[0.83 0.06 0.11 ][1 0 0] 0.021953535472746984
[0.84 0.06 0.10 ][1 0 0] 0.02071075226022949
[0.84 0.06 0.10 ][1 0 0] 0.02069826140858322
[0.84 0.06 0.10 ][1 0 0] 0.0195093015800547
[0.85 0.06 0.10 ][1 0 0] 0.018330409091236972
[0.85 0.06 0.09 ][1 0 0] 0.017104438839642612
[0.85 0.06 0.09 ][1 0 0] 0.01792169480509333
[0.85 0.06 0.09 ][1 0 0] 0.016217031383768205
[0.86 0.05 0.09 ][1 0 0] 0.015117683236563869
[0.86 0.05 0.09 ][1 0 0] 0.01481093436641068
[0.86 0.05 0.08 ][1 0 0] 0.014563732083334013
[0.87 0.05 0.08 ][1 0 0] 0.013740893744623764
[0.87 0.05 0.08 ][1 0 0] 0.013584502802642152
[0.87 0.05 0.08 ][1 0 0] 0.012811420431731651
[0.87 0.05 0.08 ][1 0 0] 0.012588752270858152
[0.87 0.05 0.08 ][0 1 0] 0.8335434414722795
[0.86 0.06 0.08 ][0 1 0] 0.8166574457987319
[0.84 0.07 0.09 ][0 1 0] 0.7959609502247489
[0.82 0.08 0.10 ][0 1 0] 0.7667863185653575
[0.80 0.09 0.11 ][0 1 0] 0.7419803629500777
[0.78 0.11 0.12 ][0 1 0] 0.7064226958160007
[0.75 0.13 0.13 ][0 1 0] 0.6703650116595594
[0.71 0.16 0.14 ][0 1 0] 0.6145673227572149
[0.67 0.19 0.15 ][0 1 0] 0.5650973847474794
[0.62 0.23 0.15 ][0 1 0] 0.5035201128245061
[0.56 0.28 0.16 ][0 1 0] 0.42696760456385946
[0.51 0.32 0.16 ][0 1 0] 0.37426984304835553
[0.45 0.39 0.16 ][0 1 0] 0.30104776794364024
[0.41 0.44 0.16 ][0 1 0] 0.253447906925031
[0.36 0.49 0.15 ][0 1 0] 0.20762783659417763
[0.32 0.54 0.14 ][0 1 0] 0.1697684204367431
[0.29 0.58 0.13 ][0 1 0] 0.13994110531897877
[0.26 0.62 0.13 ][0 1 0] 0.11478501478921287
[0.23 0.65 0.12 ][0 1 0] 0.09665604878828593
[0.22 0.67 0.11 ][0 1 0] 0.08380306576614041
[0.20 0.69 0.11 ][0 1 0] 0.07547345419618587
[0.19 0.71 0.10 ][0 1 0] 0.06518680085909506
[0.17 0.73 0.10 ][0 1 0] 0.057208830432325906
[0.17 0.74 0.09 ][0 1 0] 0.05156602530369503
[0.16 0.75 0.09 ][0 1 0] 0.04706089350030288
[0.15 0.76 0.09 ][0 1 0] 0.04303197953293731
[0.14 0.77 0.08 ][0 1 0] 0.03903237092002031
[0.14 0.78 0.08 ][0 1 0] 0.03641615165069422
[0.13 0.79 0.08 ][0 1 0] 0.033529912323920094
[0.13 0.80 0.08 ][0 1 0] 0.030884518362202438
[0.12 0.81 0.07 ][0 1 0] 0.028481220398680705
[0.12 0.81 0.07 ][0 1 0] 0.02670197699209554
[0.11 0.82 0.07 ][0 1 0] 0.025503271958091277
[0.11 0.82 0.07 ][0 1 0] 0.024024101104994443
[0.11 0.83 0.07 ][0 1 0] 0.022999049596384023
[0.10 0.83 0.07 ][0 1 0] 0.02205762731388365
[0.10 0.84 0.06 ][0 1 0] 0.02066619909329867
[0.10 0.84 0.06 ][0 1 0] 0.019008093621003776
[0.10 0.84 0.06 ][0 1 0] 0.018782938063013493
[0.09 0.85 0.06 ][0 1 0] 0.01761650910622183
[0.09 0.85 0.06 ][0 1 0] 0.016808075776727417
[0.09 0.85 0.06 ][0 1 0] 0.016412550550525176
[0.09 0.86 0.06 ][0 1 0] 0.015557087328353427
[0.08 0.86 0.06 ][0 1 0] 0.014981225852649351
[0.08 0.86 0.05 ][0 1 0] 0.014474167980246613
[0.08 0.86 0.05 ][0 1 0] 0.014076842379816792
[0.08 0.87 0.05 ][0 1 0] 0.013565080535187103
[0.08 0.87 0.05 ][0 1 0] 0.013069692653491805
[0.08 0.87 0.05 ][0 1 0] 0.012850853194447856
[0.08 0.87 0.05 ][0 1 0] 0.012231305425899792
```

Here is the forward propagation and backpropagation algorithm I implemented:-

ILi:-Input Layer input
Shape:-[1,4]

ILo:-Input Layer output
Shape:-[1,4]

HLi:-Hidden Layer input
Shape:-[1,100]

HLo:-Hidden Layer output
Shape:-[1,100]

OLi:-Output Layer input
Shape:-[1,3]

OLo:-Output Layer input
Shape:-[1,3]

Wij:- Weights between Input Layer and Hidden Layer [4,100]

Wjk:- Weights between Hidden Layer and Output Layer [4,100]

```
Wij=np.random.rand(4,100)
Wjk=np.random.rand(100,3)
def forwardpass(ILi,Outpute):
    global ILo,HLo,HLi,OLi,OLo,Wij,Wjk
    ILo=np.array(ILi) #Shape:-[1,4]
    HLi=np.matmul(ILi,Wij) # [[1,4],[4,100]]
    HLo=np.array(expit(HLi)) #Shape:-[1,100]
    OLi=np.matmul(HLo,Wjk) #[[1,100],[100,3]]
    OLo=np.array(softmax(OLi)) #Shape:-[1,3]
    Error=SE(OLo,Outpute) #Shape:-[1,3]
    print('[',end="")
    for i in OLo[0]:
        print("%.2f" % i,end=" ");
    print(']',end="")
    print(Outpute,sum(Error[0]))

def BackProp(ILi,Outpute,alpha):
    global ILo,HLo,HLi,OLi,OLo,Wij,Wjk
    dEdOLo=np.array(SEd(OLo,Outpute))
    dOLoOLi=OLo*(1-OLo)#Shape:-[1,3]
    dWjk=np.dot(HLo.T,(dEdOLo*dOLoOLi))*alpha
    dWij=np.dot(ILo.T,np.dot(Wjk,(OLo*(1-OLo)*dEdOLo).T).T*HLo*(1-HLo))*alpha
    Wij-=dWij
    Wjk-=dWjk
```

I don't understand what's going wrong, I have tried reducing the neurons in the hidden layer as well as messing around with alpha[0.1,0.01,0.001] but nothing seems to get it onto track.

Messing around with the alpha causes it to adapt to the changed output even faster, like as soon as the input changes from [1,0,0] to [0,1,0] the Predicted Probability for Class2 starts increasing proportionately to the value of alpha,i.e., greater alpha the faster it increases(which is pretty much what alpha should do anyway)

Here's what happens when i finally run it on my test data:-

Whatever was the last Class_Probability state during training is predicted for all further cases.In this example since Class2_Probability was the highest at the end of training it outputs all further test_inputs as Class2.

```
[1 0 0] [0.04600215 0.94253181 0.01146605] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04574746 0.94220717 0.01204537] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04709778 0.94090963 0.01199259] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.0449623  0.94279201 0.01224569] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04614702 0.94239695 0.01145603] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04279    0.94586446 0.01134554] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04582037 0.9421256  0.01205403] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04499829 0.94336797 0.01163374] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04601034 0.94135087 0.01263879] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.0452387  0.94293738 0.01182392] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04504582 0.94377873 0.01117545] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04413799 0.94404294 0.01181907] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.0462843  0.94174267 0.01197303] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.05024135 0.93734185 0.0124168 ] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04781183 0.94132715 0.01086101] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04485557 0.94426659 0.01087784] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04635582 0.94238965 0.01125453] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04560167 0.9428036  0.01159472] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04293738 0.94593326 0.01112936] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04492806 0.94367631 0.01139563] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04297452 0.94558126 0.01144422] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04444936 0.94395257 0.01159807] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.05080601 0.93744935 0.01174464] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04175144 0.9460157  0.01223286] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04139108 0.94659725 0.01201168] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04366487 0.94428704 0.01204808] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.0432279  0.94479472 0.01197739] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04497833 0.94359783 0.01142384] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04586366 0.94266019 0.01147615] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04398904 0.94391234 0.01209863] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04384402 0.94403927 0.01211671] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04402129 0.94433795 0.01164076] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04583841 0.94322418 0.01093741] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.0462944  0.94284241 0.01086319] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.0452387  0.94293738 0.01182392] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04794889 0.94030179 0.01174931] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04673692 0.94203717 0.01122592] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.0452387  0.94293738 0.01182392] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04721021 0.94030648 0.01248331] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04494438 0.94349066 0.01156496] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04666355 0.94169285 0.0116436 ] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04618719 0.94025169 0.01356111] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04734783 0.94039558 0.01225659] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04252896 0.94527146 0.01219958] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.0410784  0.94719177 0.01172983] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04533436 0.94236908 0.01229656] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04438119 0.94432203 0.01129678] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04609738 0.9418017  0.01210092] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04509783 0.94367338 0.01122879] InCorrect
[1 0 0] [0.04590867 0.942401   0.01169032] InCorrect
[0 1 0] [0.0228392  0.95683902 0.02032178] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02290028 0.95622627 0.02087344] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02195316 0.95638371 0.02166313] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02354612 0.9546604  0.02179348] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02223699 0.95592689 0.02183613] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02263986 0.95532912 0.02203102] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02223671 0.95595921 0.02180408] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02702391 0.95370156 0.01927453] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02277198 0.95638812 0.0208399 ] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.0239913  0.95454039 0.02146831] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02568777 0.95363505 0.02067718] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02335134 0.95560515 0.02104351] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02427133 0.95557703 0.02015164] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02214374 0.95565245 0.0222038 ] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02576075 0.95522355 0.0190157 ] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02344731 0.9566133  0.01993939] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02243672 0.95513521 0.02242808] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02444209 0.95581059 0.01974732] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02187808 0.95508379 0.02303814] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02458706 0.95522332 0.02018962] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.0214855 0.955105  0.0234095] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02431472 0.95590259 0.01978269] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02126984 0.95524599 0.02348416] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02241108 0.95583502 0.0217539 ] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02357835 0.95629567 0.02012597] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02326596 0.95643409 0.02029995] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02203126 0.95624361 0.02172513] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02124352 0.95574319 0.02301329] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.0224344  0.95551672 0.02204887] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02669121 0.95521888 0.01808991] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02480339 0.95495376 0.02024285] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02545837 0.95499661 0.01954502] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02466058 0.95555258 0.01978684] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02087918 0.95483589 0.02428494] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02240548 0.95488623 0.02270828] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02276104 0.95584266 0.0213963 ] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02237121 0.9563328  0.02129599] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02258582 0.9556093  0.02180488] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02401389 0.955494   0.02049211] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02374459 0.95487506 0.02138034] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02287425 0.95504713 0.02207862] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02249167 0.95580278 0.02170555] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02417834 0.95548273 0.02033893] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02691897 0.95375005 0.01933099] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02335798 0.95519802 0.021444  ] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02395313 0.95572731 0.02031956] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.0236058  0.95551662 0.02087759] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02348489 0.95607945 0.02043566] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02843568 0.95348119 0.01808313] Correct
[0 1 0] [0.02380982 0.95543285 0.02075733] Correct
[0 0 1] [0.01928846 0.9540461  0.02666544] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02054192 0.95427898 0.02517909] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.01953975 0.95485475 0.02560549] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02006166 0.95469965 0.02523869] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.01955431 0.95439148 0.02605421] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.01895904 0.95467582 0.02636514] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02176962 0.95347429 0.0247561 ] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.019349   0.95494324 0.02570776] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.01967753 0.95464815 0.02567433] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.0192938  0.95470464 0.02600156] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02075158 0.95523926 0.02400916] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02026045 0.95474032 0.02499923] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.01997406 0.95492516 0.02510077] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02050339 0.95396308 0.02553353] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02011159 0.95385235 0.02603606] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02010898 0.95464838 0.02524264] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.0202475  0.95501687 0.02473563] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.01909665 0.95492155 0.0259818 ] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.01859911 0.95428594 0.02711495] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02089861 0.95459811 0.02450329] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.01966197 0.95476637 0.02557166] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02078649 0.95413697 0.02507654] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.0188903  0.95467145 0.02643826] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02099487 0.95502981 0.02397532] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.01986686 0.95488956 0.02524358] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.01978704 0.95529619 0.02491677] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02123522 0.95507595 0.02368883] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02117206 0.95507665 0.02375129] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.01976324 0.95441051 0.02582625] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02013448 0.95559489 0.02427063] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.0194322  0.95500786 0.02555993] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.01957681 0.95554078 0.0248824 ] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.01968592 0.95431578 0.0259983 ] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02110093 0.95536086 0.02353821] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02031518 0.95476479 0.02492002] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.01924208 0.95490102 0.02585691] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.01975263 0.95440082 0.02584655] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02029343 0.95500019 0.02470639] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02135021 0.95503637 0.02361342] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02017182 0.95515471 0.02467347] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.01963861 0.95452695 0.02583444] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02039665 0.95515188 0.02445147] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02054192 0.95427898 0.02517909] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.01945533 0.95455845 0.02598622] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.019537   0.95448224 0.02598076] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.0201648  0.95483331 0.02500189] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02059044 0.95468262 0.02472694] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02046433 0.95500623 0.02452944] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02006918 0.9545484  0.02538243] InCorrect
[0 0 1] [0.02080652 0.95473361 0.02445987] InCorrect
Accuracy:- 33.33333333333333 %
```

Comment: The numbers you posted are the probabilities from training, not from individual runs on test cases right? Isn't this exactly what you expect to happen? As your model receives more training data it learn the correct model weights to reduce error over the training runs (you can see errors going down over time), which has the effect of getting better at accurately predicting the outcome (i.e. probability for one outcome increases over time)

Comment: "The numbers you posted are the probabilities from training" , Yes they are from training , I did ~10 traversals of the entire data. Although the model learns to reduce error on the train data but it doesn't learn any feature from it , it just sees the train data and keeps increasing/decreasing the outputs in order to reduce the error.At the end of training whatever was the last state of Class_Probabilities is used for all of the test data irrespective of what their actual class is. Like if training ended at [0,1,0] then all test data from there on are predicted as [~0,~1,~0].

Comment: I have added the output for the test run at the bottom.

Comment: In that case the first thing you should try is shuffling your training data so it isnt ordered. Does that change your results?

Comment: Shuffling the data solved the problem . Thanks a ton , I was worried the implementation was wrong.

Comment: I can't understand how shuffling the data made it work, can someone help me out?